# Swagger+Spring: is it possible to preserve the fields order in the payload?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

Assuming my payload class is:

```
public class Payload {
  private final long id;
  private final String aField;
}
```

springfox will sort the payload fields in the lexicographical order which will produce the following payload spec:

```
{
  "aField": "string",
  "id": 0
}
```

Is there any control parameter which tells the springfox to preserve the original fields order?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Hi do you find a solution (after years of updates?)

Answer (score 16):

You may use [@ApiModelProperty](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) and specify a `position` :

```
public class Payload {

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "The id", position = 1)
  private final long id;
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "The a field", position = 2)
  private final String aField;

}
```

Comment: Thx, I know of this option. Question was about triggering it on a higher level with just one setting (imagine a payload with 10-20-30.. fields).

Comment: In that case it probably would have to use reflection, and from the following links, using reflection to retrieve fields doesn't respect their appearance order (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/uIRLoKVJPFw  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097807/java-reflection-is-the-order-of-class-fields-and-methods-standardized).

Comment: OK, then the short answer seems to be "no"

Comment: Is there any workaround at global level? or Can configuration level ?

Comment: This didn't work for me in SpringFox v3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no good generic solution yet. I’d suggest to follow/upvote this issue on github: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3853

The project is not well maintained though, last commits are from 1 year ago.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the @JsonPropertyOrder once at the top of your class and the fields will be ordered in the order they are defined in the class
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-property-order-annotation.html

Comment: springfox still generates the field in lexicographical order

Comment: Jaison, you do not answer the OP. Springfox **ignores** the `@JsonProprtyOrder` annotation.